# YASDI driver "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Tags: c, driver

I have downloaded the source driver from SMA for their SunnyBoy solar array. I am trying to compile their driver but these two lines generate the following error **lvalue required as left operand of assignment**:

`(HANDLE)me->fd = (HANDLE)HFILE_ERROR;` 
and
`(HANDLE)priv->fd = (HANDLE)HFILE_ERROR;`

and just like http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/179967/, the source code builds fine on MSVC but fails on MinGW. How do I convert the lvalue to rvalue?

Comment: I don't know much about YASDI driver, but what are you trying to achieve? Getting data? Last week I was trying to get Data from SMA Sunny Boy, couldn't achieve it with python via the MODBUS protocol, I couln't get it to fully work. Then I realized I could get all of the Data via API endpoints from their HTTPS Service. If by any chance you're trying to get Data from it, just let me know

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to get data directly without using the HTTPS service, trying to develop my own mobile app to track generation data. Not having much joy trying to build the driver.

Comment: I don't know your limitation in terms of HTTP request, but you can get all the data you want from SMA Sunny Boy DIRECTLY with simple HTTP requests from their localhost service. No need to have internet for that, it's not HTTP service from their website, but from the local device's server. Do you have access to the local Web Admin panel? Like if you browse the SMA IP `192.168.1.100`, do you get a Login page with user password? Then if you have that, all the data is yours. I'll explain you what to do

Comment: Just a hint if you're interested. If you log in the web Admin Panel, go to inspect elements. On Chrome, go to Network tab, then you should see a couple of requests like `192.168.1.100/dyn/getValues.json?sid=Ys672nSD8DSGH`. The sid is just the Session ID the SMA generated to give the web app access to the data. You can get it from `192.168.1.100/dyn/login.json`. You can use it to test some requests on `/dyn/getValues.json`. but you need KEYS to get data. To get KEYS, go to any value from web panel, go to inspect element, then the KEY will be on the HTML tag tha contains the value.

Comment: I don't know if the Driver is required to setup SMA IP itself on a local network, but if it's possible without it, and if you want to go with the local HTTP request, then tell me I'll give you complete details with NodeJS (Javascript) code example to get any data that SMA have. Probably there are hundredths of data available.